# Unable to get correct nanoseconds time interval

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

My code is unable to capture proper running time of my program.

I want to display program execution time only in nanoseconds. I have used clock_monotonic to calculate time.
In my code i have used command as ./mr.py ./factorise_3_n | grep Time 
Here mr.py is the python file upto the range (0,5). This .py help to display display upto the range (0,5)

```
struct timespec start, finish;
long long int elapsed;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

factorise();

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);


elapsed = (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
printf("Time elapsed was %lld ns \n",elapsed);

return 0;
```

I expected the output of program as 
Time elapsed was 621191192 ns. 
Time elapsed was 625507930 ns. 
Time elapsed was 633012644 ns. 
Time elapsed was 627173911 ns. 
Time elapsed was 622051300 ns.

But the output is 
Time elapsed was 0 ns. 
Time elapsed was 0 ns.
Time elapsed was 0 ns. 
Time elapsed was 0 ns. 
Time elapsed was 0 ns.

Comment: You're assuming that `finish.tv_nsec` is greater than `start.tv_nsec` and ignoring the fact that the nanosecond values restart counting from zero each second.

Comment: `if (clock_gettime(...)) perror("clock"); // never mind`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Please help me how can make my code logicful?

Comment: @pmg How can get meaningful output?

Comment: `elapsed = (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec); // do not divide 1000000000.0;`

Comment: @pmg After removing / 1000000000.0 from my code.
Time elapsed was -4936729 ns 
Time elapsed was -554876 ns 
Time elapsed was 802901 ns 
Time elapsed was -8336443 ns 
Time elapsed was 500830 ns 
I want to extract time in my terminal

Comment: Suppose start was `5 seconds and 953 milliseconds`, and finish was `6 seconds and 186 milliseconds`. Your calculation will yield `186-953` (-767) milliseconds instead of 233 milliseconds

Comment: @pmg would you like to help me to edit my above mentioned code?

Comment: you need to use **both** `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec`

Comment: @pmg How can I print time in nanoseconds? Command Please
int main() {
   struct timespec start, finish;
 long long int elapsed;

 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
 
   factorise();

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);

 elapsed = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
 elapsed += (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000;
   printf("Time elapsed was %lld ns \n",elapsed +) ;

   return 0;
}

Comment: @SunilGhimire With regular numbers, when you compute 57 - 12, the result is not 5 -- it's 45.  When you compute 41 - 18, the result is not -7, it's 23.  My point is that you don't subtract just the 1's digit, you have to subtract *all* the digits, and sometimes you have to "borrow" from a higher-order digit.

Comment: Similarly, when you subtract two struct timespecs, you can't just subtract the `tv_nsec` field, you have to subtract both fields, and sometimes you have to "borrow" from `tv_sec` if the difference in the `tv_nsec` values comes out negative.

Comment: Perhaps you thought that `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` were two versions of the same time.  But that's not it at all.  A `struct timespec` represents a possibly-fractional time in two parts: `tv_sec` is the integer part, and `tv_nsec` is the fractional part.

Comment: @SteveSummit long long diff =  (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000 
                  + (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);

printf("Time elapsed was %lld ns \n", diff);  By Martin Wickman
This code completely work to solve my problem
Do you have any idea,
How can I display this time to .csv file?
./mr.py ./factorise_3_n |grep Time | awk ' ' '{print $6}' | sed 'nsec/nsec//'>16.csv
I had tried this command but didn't work

Comment: If it prints correctly when you run your `factorise` program by itself, but doesn't show up after running it through that pipeline to turn the output into a csv file, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: By the way, your `sed` invocation looks pretty suspicious.  (And if you want the output in a different format, why not change your `printf` statement, rather than trying to use a three-element pipeline with `grep`, `awk`, and `sed` to massage it?)

Comment: @SteveSummit any helpful command to take nanoseconds time into csv file ?
Or Is it impossible?

Comment: It is 100% completely and totally possible, but you might want to ask a second question about it.  I'd start by simplifying your pipeline to `./mr.py ./factorise_3_n |grep Time | awk ' ' '{print $6}' >16.csv` or just `./mr.py ./factorise_3_n >16.csv`.

Comment: @SteveSummit You are completely right but I am still get blank .txt file

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle when seconds roll over. This should do the trick:

```
long long diff =  (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000000 
                  + (finish.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);

printf("Time elapsed was %lld ns \n", diff);
```

Comment: Thank you very much..
Do you any idea of taking this nanosecond time to .csv file ? I have used command but it show blank .txt file
./mr.py ./factorise_3_n |grep Time | awk ' ' '{print $6}' | sed 's/s//'>16.csv

Answer (score 1):

Handling `struct timespec` is error-prone. I suggest always converting the result of `clock_gettime` to a 64-bit integer number of nanoseconds and only then doing the calculations.  E.g.:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

uint64_t monotonic_now() {
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    return t.tv_sec * UINT64_C(1000000000) + t.tv_nsec;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t start = monotonic_now();
    uint64_t finish = monotonic_now();
    printf("%.9f seconds\n", (finish - start) * 1e-9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much